# Приоритет операторов в C++

Tags: c++, операторы, приоритет

Если смотреть на [таблицу](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), то можно заметить, что приоритет операторов инкремента и декремента выше, чем приоритет логических операторов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако этот код выведет 100.

```
int x, y, z;
x = y = z = 0;
x++ && y++ && ++z;
cout << x << y << z;
```

Почему сначала не будут выполняться унарные операции, если их приоритет выше?

Comment: Строго говоря приоритет не имеет отношения к порядку вычисления выражения. Приоритет лишь расставляет скобки. Компилятор гарантирует что аргументы операции будут вычислены до самой операции и больше ничего. А в случае с `&&` ситуация ещё сложнее. Сперва вычисляется левый аргумент, если он не ноль, то правый и затем операция логического "и". Если левый операнд - ноль, то больше вообще ничего не будет вычислено. [Logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

Comment: Ну подумайте для начала хотя бы о том, ***когда*** выполняется ***постфиксный*** инкремент? Например, в выражении `*a++` — по *вашей* логике, сначала выполнится инкремент, а уже потом разыменование, а на самом деле? И еще раз: компилятор встречает логическое выражение, поэтому он применяет правило сокращенного вычисления, так что какой бы приоритет не был в выражениях, они **не вычисляются**.  Вы, похоже, не очень верно представляете себе, что такое приоритет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приоритет операторов не задает жестко порядок вычисления. Грубо говоря, он контролирует только то, как компилятор расставляет скобки в выражении.

Пример: `a + b == c * d` превращается в `(a + b) == (c * d)`. Но скобки не заставляют нас считать `*` до `+`, это остается на усмотрение компилятора

Но конечно, скобки немного ограничивают порядок вычисления, в том смысле что перед тем, как вычислить оператор, нужно сначала вычислить его аргументы (операнды), т.е. здесь `==` должен вычисляться после `+` и `*`.

Но и то, если не указано обратное, сайд-эффекты (например увеличение значения из-за `x++`) могут происходить позднее, чем просто завершение его вычисления - надо читать https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Заметьте, как тут описывают `&&`:

> Every value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of ... && ... is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument.

"Вычисление" и "сайд-эффекты" описываются отдельно.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что сокращенное вычисление.

```
x++ && ...
```

Чему там равно `x`? Нулю? Но `0 && ...` с чем угодно даст `false`, так что вычислять все остальное по стандарту уже не нужно.

Ну, и не вычисляем...